# How to access watson assistant using python?

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I want to implement a particular chatbot which has been created and trained using IBM Watson Assistant on a website, which is using Django/flask at the backend so how can I integrate that particular chatbot on my website?
Please help me by providing any link or video guide

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on whether you just want to embed the chatbot or deeply integrate it with additional logic.

For embedding the chatbot with a website (like yours build with Flask or Django), you could use the integrations offered by Watson Assistant. It is either [customized](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-chat) or [IBM-branded](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-link).

Another option is to utilize the [Python SDK for the IBM Watson services](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk). Here, you would build the UI on your own and drive the dialog. I have built a [simple text-based command line tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/) with that SDK and am able to converse with Watson Assistant.

Comment: My concept is something like this --- I have already trained the IBM Watson Assistant using some intents, entities and dialog , Now I want to develop a web app in flask or django so that whenever user will give input on my web app that data will be passed to watson assistant and it will produce the output respect to that input and will return only that dialogue which it was supposed to return based on the user intent and user will see that output on the web. Now I just want to know how can I pass that input to watson and how can i receive the output from the watson at our backend?

Comment: See my links to the Python SDK and how I use the API functions in the provided tool. There is a version for V1 and V2 API. It demonstrates how to obtain user input, send it to Watson and return the received message back to the user.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it really helped me

Comment: In that case please upvote and mark as answered